# do not initiate tinymce on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, tinymce

I am currently using tinyMCE and using a oninit function to add a custom footer to the messageBody. I have no problem getting the footer inside the editor but I run into a problem when a user adds an attachment which causes the page to be refreshed. All the content except for the footer is deleted from the editor. (The code is doing what it is suppose to do!) Is there a way to have tinyMCE not re initiate when a page refreshes or is there a different route I could take? Code below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- Intiate tinyMCE -->
    tinyMCE.init({

    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount",
    "apply_source_formatting" : true,
    "paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste" : false,
    "paste_retain_style_properties" : "all",
    //The below two lines to fix enter problem after a pastes is done by the user
    "force_br_newlines" : true,
    "force_p_newlines" : false,

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "undo,redo,|,link,unlink,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen,|,wordcount",

    //Calling a new CSS file to set Default Font and Text size
    content_css : "/js/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/custom.css" + new Date().getTime(),
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    oninit: function(){
        tinyMCE.get('messageBody').setContent('<br><br><p>This message was generated by the Tool <br> If you are experiencing any issues with the Tool, please contact us <a href="mailto:someone@something.com">here</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com">The Tool</a></p>');
    }



    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you have the user upload the attachment using a hidden iframe because then your main page with the tinyMCE will not be refreshed. Are you currently using a generic file upload? If you want to change to use a packaged one I've used plupload for a while and its a very useful file upload utility.

Comment: That could be an option. Really did not want to put the page in frames but looking at it, it is probably my only way. Thanks

Comment: No don't put your page in an iframe, just have a iframe to do the upload so that your main page with the tinymce doesn't get refreshed. There's many examples out there of simple uploading via an iframe. Good luck :)